# Sound problem, Dummy output sound problem on Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am having the dummy sound problem and there is no sound, I have tried most of the solution on the internet but nothing worked.

More details:

```
$ uname -r
5.3.0-46-generic
$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
$ alsamixer
```

[image]

even the same when choosing all option

Sound settings:

[image]

Comment: Did you reboot? (Always works in my case.)

Comment: Yes I tried after each solution I try

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on ubuntu running light x11. Try if it works for you too.

`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
pavucontrol`

Now switch to "Configuration" tab (You might see only 2 tabs. Go right from here.)
Select something on the lines of "analog sterio".

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue for me (on pop OS) :

```bsh
rm -r ~/.config/pulse
pulseaudio -k
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

Found here :
https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/